# Teamcity 2017.2 with MS-SQL express issue

Tags: sql-server, java, windows-server-2016, teamcity

I am using [CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Benchmark 1.0.0 Level 2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071CVKL6W) on EC2 with [Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54284).

When coming to setup [Teamcity 2017.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2017/11/teamcity-2017-2-released/) I receive the following error:

> Login failed for user '********'. ClientConnectionId:287ee400-4811-41b6-847f-02b843642553 (after 10 attempt(s); total time spent waiting 542.841 ms; driver version 6.0.8112.100; java.version=1.8.0_151; jdk.tls.client.protocols=[]; jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=[MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224]; jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=[SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224])
>
> SQL exception: Login failed for user '********'. ClientConnectionId:287ee400-4811-41b6-847f-02b843642553 (after 10 attempt(s); total time spent waiting 542.841 ms; driver version 6.0.8112.100; java.version=1.8.0_151; jdk.tls.client.protocols=[]; jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=[MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224]; jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=[SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224])

I have setup the db as described here:
[Setting up TeamCity with MS SQL Server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+TeamCity+with+MS+SQL+Server#SettingupTeamCitywithMSSQLServer-CreatededicateduserforTeamCitywithSQLserverauthentication)

I tried working through a few manuals but nothing seems to work. I have the right credentials and did not change any default security features in windows.

I can successfully Telnet 1433 on localhost.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved  it.
Installed MS-SQL Server again and it worked.

Microsoft does black magic.